# keep top $k$ weighted edges for each node

Tags: graph-theory

I have a weighted undirected fully connected graph. I want to exact a subgraph that each node in the subgraph has exactly $k$ top-weighted edges. Is there a way to find such subgraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a subgraph may not exist. Consider the complete undirected edge wieghted graph below.

[image]